how to implement TextSearch with HierarchicalDataTemplate for TreeView?
I have a multi-level TreeView that implements data binding, just like:
<TreeView
    IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
    IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"
    TextSearch.TextPath="Config.Name"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Connections, Mode=OneWay}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        ... for style
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" 
            DataType="{x:Type models:TreeNode_Connection}">
            
            ... for level-1 node, label binding Config.Name
            
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" 
                    DataType="{x:Type models:TreeNode_Database}">
                    
                    ... for level-2 node, label binding Name
                    
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
                            DataType="{x:Type models:TreeNode_Module}">
                        
                            ... for level-3 node, label binding Name
                            
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

I hope that each layer can implement the function of TextSearch, but currently only the first layer has achieved it. I have tried various methods, such as:

Add TextSearch.TextPath to the HierarchicalDataTemplate for every-level.
Add TextSearch.TextPath to the ItemContainerStyle for every-level.
Unifying the variable names of each level as Name.


But all these attempts were ineffective, how should I implement this feature?

I search the (backing) "data source" and "surface" a key or index or collection of results. The UI is an "illusion" and not intended for querying per se.

@GerrySchmitz what do you mean?

This is a simple text search feature that is implemented by the base type ItemsControl. It does not know how to traverse  your tree structure. You will have to implement your  own search.
